# Push String onto Array in PHP returns as null

Tags: php

In my PHP, I have the following Array..

```
$json = array(
 "ack" => "success",
 "totalPages" => $total_pages,
 "currentPage" => $pageno,
 "results" => array()
);
```

I go through an array, increment a counter. Where I would return my encoded json, I add the counter into the `$json` array.

```
echo $counter //returns the number
array_push($json['count'], $counter) //returns null
```

How can I push the $counter into the 'count' object?

Comment: `$json['count'] = $counter; echo $json['count'];` ?

Comment: where is `$counter` set to a value? If it is not, it will be `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `$counter` would be an integer variable, instead of an array. [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) takes an array for the first parameter, and the additional values to add to that array.

In your case, it looks like you're wanting to set the array's key for `count` to the variable `$counter`, which you can do like so:

```php
$json = array(
  'ack' => 'success',
  'totalPages' => $total_pages,
  'currentPage' => $pageno,
  'results' => array(),
  'count' => 0,
);

$json['count'] = $counter;
```

**Edit:**

Additionally, if you're setting the variable above for your response, and you're not doing any further code changes, you can just declare your `$json` array with the `$counter` variable, similar to how you have for `totalPages` and `currentPage`, and for completeness:

```php
$json = array(
  'ack' => 'success',
  'totalPages' => $total_pages,
  'currentPage' => $pageno,
  'results' => array(),
  'count' => $counter, // Set the $counter variable here, straight away!
);
```

Answer (score 2):

To update (or set) an array key you would not use `array_push()`, but simply:

```
$json['count'] = $counter;
```

Comment: Thank you Ron, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

**no need [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.array-push.php) for this situation, you should do as follows**

```php
$json = array(
 "ack" => "success",
 "totalPages" => $total_pages,
 "currentPage" => $pageno,
 "results" => array()
);

$json['count']=$counter;

print_r($json); //print array for humans and see
```

**if you use array_push in other scenarios u can use as such**

**for example ,**
`$array[]="item";`

```
$array=[];
$array[]="foo";
$array[]="bar";


print_r($array); //["foo","bar"]
```